How to retain values on invoice after throwing an error using user event script?
I have developed line level amount validation user event script. I throw error if amount is invalid. When user enters invalid amount, user can see error but once he go back those lines go away from the Invoice. Is it possible to retain those lines on Invoice? Please advice!
     function beforeSubmit(context) {
       // Loop through each line item
        for (var i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
           var lineAmount = invoiceRecord.getSublistValue({
        sublistId: "item",
        fieldId: "amount",
        line: i,
      });

     if(lineAmount==0)
     {
      throw("invalid amount");
     }
      
    }

      }


A user event is a script running on the server side.
For your use case, you need to use a client script.
